# Image to line algorithm

Tags: algorithm, drawing

I built a plotter that draws with a normal pen and have written software where the user can draw lines (x,y,x1,y1) or circles(x,y,r).

I  also managed to read and convert and then draw some of the one-line traveling salesman problem [solution](http://www.tsp.gatech.edu/data/ml/monalisa.html).

I am looking for an algorithm to make a pencil or hatching drawing of a bmp and output a list of lines, circles or pixels.  I had a look at halftone and it kind of works, but looking for something a bit more…. artistic .

Any ideas where I start ?

Answer (score 0):

the term you may be looking for is "image vectorization" : http://www.google.cl/search?q=image+vectorization